# celery task is not called when it is shown on flower dashboard

Tags: python, celery, fastapi

I am using celery alongside fastapi. I could see celery task registered from flower dashboard, however, the task does not get called. I could neither see any error or any kind of logs.

This is how I have setup

app/app/core/celery_app.py

```
from celery import Celery

celery_app = Celery("workers", broker="amqp://guest@queue//")

celery_app.conf.task_routes = {
    "app.workers.download_and_generate_logs_df.download_and_generate_logs_df": "main-queue"
}
```

app/app/workers/download_and_generate_logs_df.py

```
from app.core.celery_app import celery_app


@celery_app.task()
def download_and_generate_logs_df(repo, token) -> str:
    print("celery task entered")
    if repo.provider == "gitlab":
        gitlab_repo_url = f"https://oauth2:{token}@gitlab.com/{repo.fullpath}"
        root_dir = os.getcwd()  # /app
        clone_url = f"git clone {gitlab_repo_url} --bare"
        os.chdir("./app/bare-gits/")
        gits_dir = os.getcwd()
        if os.path.isdir(gits_dir):
            if os.path.isdir(f"{repo.name}.git"):
                # create a logs file and save it to logs folder
                print("already exist")
                generate_logs(repo.name)
                return {"msg": "Calculated"}
        else:
            os.system(clone_url)
            generate_logs(repo.name)
            return {"msg": "Cloned and calculated"}

        os.chdir(root_dir)
```

app/app/worker-start.sh

```
celery -A app.core.celery_app worker -l info -Q main-queue -c 1
```

app/app/main.py

```
@app.get("/test-repo-calculation")
def test_repo_calculation(*, db: Session = Depends(get_db), user_id: int, repo_id: int):
    celery_task = celery_app.send_task(
                "app.workers.download_and_generate_logs_df",
                args=[repo.name, token],
            )
    print("celery_task", celery_task)
    return {"msg": "Calculation is in progress"}
```

This is what I see in flower dashboard and logs

[image]

[image]

This is what my project structure looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's related but according to [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/routing.html#automatic-routing):

```
celery_app.conf.task_routes = {
    "app.workers.download_and_generate_logs_df.download_and_generate_logs_df": "main-queue"
}
```

should be:

```
celery_app.conf.task_routes = {
    "app.workers.download_and_generate_logs_df.download_and_generate_logs_df": {"queue": "main-queue"}
}
```

**EDIT**:

1. you need to register your task:

```
celery_app = Celery("workers", broker="amqp://guest@queue//")
```

should be:

```
celery_app = Celery("workers", broker="amqp://guest@queue//", include=["app.workers.download_and_generate_logs_df"])
```

[image: You should see your task here]

2. change:

```
celery_task = celery_app.send_task(
                "app.workers.download_and_generate_logs_df",
                args=[repo.name, token],
            )
```

to:

```
celery_task = celery_app.send_task(
                "app.workers.download_and_generate_logs_df.download_and_generate_logs_df",
                args=[repo.name, token],
            )
```

Comment: still the task is not run. I get the task id but it is neither shown in the list of tasks in flower dashboard nor the function gets called. I could only see the worker list as online.

Comment: can you share your folders tree?

Comment: Updated my question with project structure.

Comment: Updated my answer, please let me know if it works

Comment: @Serenity did you see my answer's edit?